# Minimal system requirements for .NET Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, motorola, windows-embedded

I have hardware with Microsoft Embedded Windows CE 4.1 (CE .NET) / CPU Intel XScale PXA250 / Memory 32 MB RAM/32 MB ROM.

Is there possible to run .NET CF 3.5 on hardware this type? Or may be only .NET CF 2.0?

Comment: As I mentioned, CF 3.5 can run on only on CE4.2 devices: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that there is a version for Windows CE 4.2, it may work also on 4.1 because there are no major differences in the kernel between those two releases:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947559
It's not granted that it could run on any Windows CE 4.2 device. The .NET CF requires that some OS components are part of the image and if they aren't you'll have to rebuild the OS image for your device adding the required components.
IIRC you can't debug applications on CE 4.x, but I'm not 100% sure about this point.