# How to deploy and debug VS 2008 SmartDevice Application in Win CE 4.1 device or emulator

Tags: windows-ce, emulation, smart-device, smart-device-framework

I have built an smart device app in VS 2008. I could deployed and debugged in Windows Mobile OS devices successfully.

But, I must have to deploy and debug the same app usign Windows CE 4.1 device as well. The problem is compact framework version that indicates the app is higher version of compact framework so i can not run the app in CE 4.1 device.

So I have tried to debug the app using emulator.

I would like to ask that I have failed to debug the app in any emulator which is listed in VS 2008 devices list.

I'd be glad if there is a workaround to solve the issue!

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this topic: [Minimal system requirements for .NET Compact Framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530262/minimal-system-requirements-for-net-compact-framework-3-5)

It may help you. Deploying maybe possible but debugging will be very slow if it is working. I tried this with a PPC2003-device and this was horribly slow.

You have too keep in mind that CF3.5 needs much more CPU and Memory.

Comment: yes! you are right! so I figured that is highly impossible to solve the problem using that way...
well I developed the program with VS 2003 and then I could deploy and debug...
thanks a lot for your comment!

Comment: Don't forget to rate the answer ;) Thanks in advance!